# Excel vba, Make cell containing hyperlink appear in email body

Tags: vba, excel, email, hyperlink

I have a code that is sending an email to users when a submittal date is added. In the body of this email I am referring to a cell that contains a hyperlink to a folder. the destination of this hyperlink is appearing but it is not active, meaning it appears only as text. Here is my code, and the hyperlink cell is referred to in the email body

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim KeyCells As Range


    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("J3:J1000")


    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been
        ' changed.
        ' Place your code here.
Dim answer As String
Dim SubmitLink As String

SubmitLink = Target.Offset(, -8).Value

answer = MsgBox("Do you wish to save this change. An Email will be sent to the User", vbYesNo, "Save the change")

If answer = vbNo Then Cancel = True
If answer = vbYes Then
'open outlook type stuff
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OlObjects = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set newmsg = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
'add recipients
'newmsg.Recipients.Add ("Name Here")
newmsg.Recipients.Add Worksheets("Coordinator").Range("Q4").Value
'add subject
newmsg.Subject = Worksheets("Coordinator").Range("O3").Value
'add body
newmsg.Body = "Dear User, New Submittal ( " & SubmitLink & " ) has been Added in submittal Log. Please Investigate the Change" & vbLf & vbLf & vbLf & "Sincerely,"

newmsg.Display 'display
newmsg.Send 'send message
'give conformation of sent message
MsgBox "Modification confirmed", , "Confirmation"



End If
   '     MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."

End If
End Sub
```

[Explanatory Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Db2hT.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment the e-mail you're creating is Plain Text, and because of this it's essentially down to the client receiving the e-mail as to whether or not it will automatically attempt to turn things which look like they should be hyperlinks into actual hyperlinks. A file path in the format `C:\Path\to\file.xls` is not something this would ordinarily apply to.

The proper way to do this would be to use the `HTMLbody` property of your `MailItem` `newmsg`, and to parse your information into HTML specifying what exactly should be a hyperlink.

A slightly 'cheaty' but quite a simple way of doing this using only Plain Text would be to amend your path slightly. If you append `file://` to your path *some* e-mail clients including Outlook will automatically create a hyperlink for you. So, for example, you would change your `newmsg.Body` line to read:

`newmsg.Body = "Dear User, New Submittal ( file://" & SubmitLink & " ) has been Added in submittal Log. Please Investigate the Change" & vbLf & vbLf & vbLf & "Sincerely,"`

Which would produce a hyperlink like `file://C:\Path\to\file.xls`. Obviously if the e-mail client your recipients are using does not create automatic hyperlinks as I've described here, then you will need to build a `HTMLBody` to get hyperlinks working correctly.

**Edit** in response to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293238/excel-vba-make-cell-containing-hyperlink-appear-in-email-body/35293806?noredirect=1#comment58324895_35293806), to give a brief explanation of how you would use `HTMLBody`. Instead of setting `newmsg.Body` you instead set `newmsg.HTMLBody` to your HTML formatted message. In the very simplest of terms you could build your existing message as follows.

```
    Dim emailBody As String

    '   At the very minimum your basic HTML page is made up of:
    '   <html>
    '   <body>
    '   Your message, including any formatting or hyperlniks.
    '   </body>
    '   </html>
    '
    emailBody = "<html><body><font face=""Arial, sans-serif"">"
    emailBody = emailBody & "Dear User, New Submittal "
    emailBody = emailBody & "<a href=""" & SubmitLink & """>" & SubmitLink & "</a>"
    emailBody = emailBody & " has been Added in submittal Log. Please Investigate the Change<br><br><br>Sincerely,"
    emailBody = emailBody & "</font></body></html>"

    newmsg.HTMLBody = emailBody
```

I would suggest taking at a look [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp) if you want to learn further about building HTML.

Comment: Thank you for your help andshrew, your comment and thorough explanation also gave me more understanding about the issue.My recipients and I are using outlook, so the 'cheaty' way works, but for some reason it is telling me 'cannot find file. Verify path or internet address is correct', even though it is a proper hyperlink path leading to a folder.

Comment: Could you kindly explain how I could incorporate a HTMLbody into my Worksheet_Change code. Because I want the email to be sent on change. I have looked up building an HTMLbody but did not know how to add it to my code. Sorry but I am a beginner. Thank you

Comment: @Abd.Y I've added an example of HTMLBody to my answer which hopefully explains how you would use this. Regarding the issue of the link not working due to it being unable to find the file... it may sound silly but are you absolutely sure that the path you're linking to is correct and that that the recipient has permission to access it?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help andshrew. I really benefited from all your comments. The HTMLBody code worked perfectly, I implemented it as it gives more flexibility. It feels very rewarding when you finally crack a code :)

Comment: As for the 'cheaty' way, it does work when I tried with another folder destination. Why it did not work for my folder destination is because it has brackets () in the name, so the hyperlink is stopping before the bracket. I mean the destination folder is something like this: C:\Users\ME\Dropbox (XXXX)\Users log...So the hyperlink is stopping at Dropbox because of the bracket. Anyway, I used the HTMLBody because it is more convenient. Again, I really appreciate your help. Stay awesome